# HLSL shaders compilation error - failed to open source file

Tags: shader, directx, hlsl

I'm currently creating a program that uses Directx 11. I'm working with shaders written in HLSL. I have a few shader files in specific structure:

```
global.hlsl
lighting.hlsl
folderA/shader1VS.hlsl
folderA/shader1PS.hlsl
```

File **global.hlsl** has definitions of structers like DirectionalLight, PointLight because I have cbuffer for lights in that file (that uses those structures).

File **lighting.hlsl** has functions for lighting calculcations and I want it to use those structures from global.hlsl file (DirectionalLight etc.). So this file includes global as:

```
#include "global.hlsl"
```

File **shader1PS.hlsl** uses global.hlsl and lighting.hlsl so it includes them as:

```
#include "../global.hlsl"
#include "../lighting.hlsl"
```

I'm checking if shaders are correct when I hit the Build solution button in VS2022 (I think it uses built-in shader compiler?). With that - everything is ok. But to use those shaders, I'm compiling them with **D3DCompileFromFile** function. Unfortunately I have error about those includes for shader1PS.hlsl file: *"failed to open source file 'global.hlsl'*.

I think the problem is that the shader compiler does a very simple include - literally copy and paste. And since shader1PS includes lighting.hlsl, it will have *#include "global.hlsl"* inserted which is an incorrect relative path (from folderA/shader1PS.hlsl to global.hlsl).

Does anybody know how I can fix that without changing the file-folder structure (I don't want to have all shader files in one folder)?

**EDIT1:**
Below are fragments of my code.

Compiling pixel shader:

```cpp
DxResPtr<ID3DBlob> pixelShaderBlob, errorBlob;
HRESULT result;

D3D_SHADER_MACRO globalMacros[] = { 
    // here are some macros
    NULL, NULL
};

if (!pixelShaderFilePath.empty())
{
    result = D3DCompileFromFile(pixelShaderFilePath.c_str(), globalMacros, D3D_COMPILE_STANDARD_FILE_INCLUDE, "main", "ps_5_0", shaderCompilationFlags, 0, pixelShaderBlob.reset(), errorBlob.reset());
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        if(errorBlob)
        {
            OutputDebugStringA((char*)errorBlob->GetBufferPointer());
        }
    }

    result = g_device->CreatePixelShader(pixelShaderBlob->GetBufferPointer(), pixelShaderBlob->GetBufferSize(), NULL, m_pixelShader.reset());
}
```

And those 3 shader files:

**global.hlsl**:

```
#ifndef __GLOBAL_HLSL__
#define __GLOBAL_HLSL__

// structs, cbuffers, functions

#endif
```

**lighting.hlsl**:

```
#ifndef __LIGHTING_HLSL__
#define __LIGHTING_HLSL__

#include "global.hlsl"

// lighting functions that uses structs from global.hlsl

#endif
```

**shader1PS.hlsl**:

```
#ifndef __SHADER1PS_HLSL__
#define __SHADER1PS_HLSL__

#include "../global.hlsl"
#include "../lighting.hlsl"

// main pixel shader that uses functions from global.hlsl and lighting.hlsl

#endif
```

Comment: Have you read the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3dcompiler/nf-d3dcompiler-d3dcompilefromfile *"`pInclude parameter` : an optional pointer to an ID3DInclude interface that the compiler uses to handle include files. If you set this parameter to NULL and the shader contains a #include, a compile error occurs. You can pass the D3D_COMPILE_STANDARD_FILE_INCLUDE macro, which is a pointer to a default include handler. This default include handler includes files that are relative to the current directory"*

Comment: I am passing this macro.

Comment: You should some some code instead of making us guess what you're really doing.

Comment: Are you trying to use ``D3DCompileFromFile`` from the legacy DirectX SDK or are you using one from the Windows SDK?

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I'm not sure. How can I check that?

Comment: Do you have the DirectX SDK installed?

Comment: The problem is likely to be easily solved by renaming your HLSL include files with the `.hlsli` extension instead of '`.hlsl` . The compiler is probably looking for a shader entry point function in your include files, and a compiler error occurs. The Visual Studio HLSL compiler will ignore `.hlsli` files on the other hand and not try to compile them. Just be sure to leave the HLSL properties page blank for your include files, and VS should compile your actual shaders successfully.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I installed VS2022 with "Game development with C++", I didn't install anything else extra.

Comment: @MaicoDeBlasio it's still the same

Comment: Have you tried compiling your HLSL shaders after placing your header files in the same folder as the source files to eliminate filepath as the problem?

Comment: @MaicoDeBlasio yes, I did and it was working but the thing is that I don't want to have all shaders in one folder (the same way I don't have all .cpp/.h files in one folder)

Answer (score 1):

First, if you add a file with the extension `.hlsl` to a Visual Studio project, it will attempt to build it with FXC.EXE. You should call your include files something like `.hlsli` instead. If you don't want your `.hlsl` files to be built at runtime, you need to modify the MSBuild properties for it so it's "Not included in build".

Generally, relative paths in `#include` statements are non-portable, so the best option is to use:

```
#include "global.hlsli"
```

Then provide the appropriate path (`..\`) to the compiler via `/I` (or `AdditionalIncludeDirectories` for HLSL MSBuild rules). You'd have to implement your own include handler to look in the additional paths if you want to do compilation at runtime.

Comment: Well, I have empty AdditionalIncludeDirectories and yet VS sees no problem with those shaders. The problem is still with compiling them with D3DCompileFromFile function. It looks like one compiler (fxc.exe if I understand it right) knows what to do with those relative paths but the one that is used by the D3D function doesn't.